# Failure performing sObject describe connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: community, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, sfdx-plugin

I have started using VScode for my salesforce development , while i could setup my application in the IDE and retrieve all the necessary code.

I find i'am unable to refresh `standard object`. but i can refresh `Custom object`. i.e when i run `SFDX : Refresh SObject Defination` and chose `Standard Object` i keep getting
`ended with error Failure performing sObject describe connect ETIMEDOUT`  but when i do for `custom Object` it run's successfully, no other are impaired as well , i can push, pull, run test etc...

So can someone explain me why this error comes and how can i resolve it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem at the moment, but my error is `sfdx sobject definitions refresh ended with error Failure performing sObject describe aborted`